# How to configure spring boot to bind a supplier to a rabbitmq queue with spring-cloud-stream and rabbit-binder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I want to send messages to a rabbitmq queue `demo-queue` using a very simple spring boot app:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Supplier<String> sampleProducer() {
        return () -> {
            System.out.println("producing message");
            return LocalDateTime.now().toString();
        };
    }
}
```

I currently have the following `application.yml`:

```
---
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
```

When I start the application it logs that its connected to rabbitmq and prints out messages in the console written in the `sampleProducer`. So the supplier is started and queried for new messages. However I don't see a queue in rabbitmq being created and filled with the produced messages.

The `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm lost in the spring documentation and examples because I haven found an example in there that puts a message created by a `Supplier` into a queue.

What do I need to do in order to actually send the messages to the queue? I would like to only change `application.yml` and not add additional code if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ producers don't publish to queues, they publish to exchanges.

Spring Cloud Stream producers don't bind a queue to the destination exchange by default.

RabbitMQ discards unroutable messages by default.

You can add

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.sampleProducer-out-0.producer.required-groups=foo
```

and the producer will bind a queue to the destination exchange.